# LED module retrofit into old quad fluorescent not working

Tags: led, recessed-lighting, retrofit

I am replacing a bathroom "quad tube" fluorescent recessed ceiling fixture with a Halo recessed downlight LED "module" (RL560WH6940R). This module is the kind that comes with a male edison screw mount so all you have to do is take out the old build and screw the module in:

[image: Halo recessed downlight LED]

Here is a picture of the old quad fluorescent  bulb:

[image: Quad fluorescent bulb]

The fluorescent bulb fits into a reflector housing shown here:

[image: reflector housing]

This reflector trim has metal springs on the side that allowed me to remove it from the recessed housing in the ceiling. I cut off the white and black wires from this reflector trim leaving the black and white wires. I then wired in a female edison screw mount piece that allows me to attach the Halo retrofit LED module.

However, I cannot get the Halo LED module to work in the bathroom fixture. I know the LED module works because when I screw it into my desklamp it lights up perfectly.

Also, I have screwed in two *other* LED bulbs (a 9W Sylvania and a 15W GE PAR30) into the bathroom fixture, and *those* light up.

Why doesn't the combination of the Halo LED module with the bathroom fixture work?

**UPDATE**: It appears that the ballast for the original quad fluorescent bulb is above the housing and not visible. I would have to take out the housing to remove the ballast. To remove the housing would be difficult (it is probably attached to a beam). However, I found that the Feit LED modules (1200274) work even **with** the ballast.

Comment: I don't quite follow how that compact fluorescent lamp works with an Edison socket. There must be a ballast+adapter involved, and you're removing both that and the CFL tube in order to test the Sylvania, GE, and Halo units? Also, what kind of control are you working with: a simple toggle switch, or a dimmer/timer/smart switch of some kind?

Comment: Yes, how is the ballast mounted into your fixture?

Comment: How on earth are you getting the Edison base to screw into a CFL socket?

Comment: I updated my question to better explain how I am attaching the retrofit LED module.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the fixture with neither the reflector nor the retrofit module in place?